# Can we define UDF to extract characteristic (for example: mean) from a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a large dataset (TB worth of Big Data) that is in a form of Spark Dataframe. I want to create a UDF to extract mean of specific columns. How do i go about doing that?

Comment: Do you need the mean of all rows for a specific column, or the mean of multiple columns for each row?

Comment: Mean of all rows for a specific column

Comment: Spark has a built-in mean function you can use for this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.mean.html#pyspark.sql.functions.mean